# React Native custom RefreshControl component doesn't work in FlatList on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a custom component for `RefreshControl` made so I can change the `title property` that the RefreshControl offers.

In the end this is the return of my custom `RefreshControl` component:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!refreshing && counter > 0) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setCounter(previousValue => previousValue + 1)
            }, 500)
        }

        !refreshing && counter === 0 && setCounter(previousValue => previousValue + 1)
    }, [refreshing])

    return (
            <RefreshControl
                onRefresh={onRefresh}
                refreshing={refreshing}
                title={counter > 1 ? 'Refreshing': 'Loading data'}
                tintColor={Colors.main}
                titleColor={Colors.main}
            />
        )
```

This component of mine is used as follow in `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
     ref={flatListRef}
     style={styles.flatList}
     contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
     data={data}
     renderItem={renderItem}
     keyExtractor={item => item.number.toString()}
     refreshControl={
         <MyRefreshControl
               onRefresh={makeRequest}
               refreshing={isRefreshing}
         />
     }
 />
```

This implementation `works great on iOS` but on `Android` the `FlatList` simply disappear, won't even show on the screen, but if I add directly the `RefreshControl` from the `react-native` will work.

How can I resolve this?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Passing a custom component as a `refreshControl` is sparsely documented, but if you're supplying your own component, you need to spread additional props into your component and pass them through to `RefreshControl`. So you'll want your code to look like this:

```
export const MyRefreshControl = ({
  refreshing,
  onRefresh,
  counter,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <RefreshControl
      onRefresh={onRefresh}
      refreshing={refreshing}
      title={counter > 1 ? 'Refreshing' : 'Loading data'}
      tintColor={Colors.main}
      titleColor={Colors.main}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

And the callsite will remain the same.

Comment: Omg, this saved me a lot of time! Had the same disappearing problem in Android.

Comment: 2023 and this is still the only well-detailed solution. Thank you!